# Synonym words are not being stemmed correctly in text search

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

In PostgreSQL, I have a text search configuration with a synonym dictionary and then I use the english_stem file. The problem is that for example, I have the word 'tv' as a synonym for 'television'. Thus when I input:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('my_config', 'tv') returns 'television':1
```

However

```
SELECT to_tsvector('my_config', 'television') returns 'televis':1
```

Thus we see after the word gets passed through to the synonym dictionary, the stemming dictionary ignores it.

My text search configuration is written as:

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION test_config
ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, word, hword, asciihword
WITH syn_file, english_stem
```

The main problem is my search then gives no results with synonym words.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. You can create the synonym file like this:

> television tv

2. Instead of a synonym dictionary you can use a [thesaurus dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-THESAURUS):

   - In the directory $SHAREDIR/tsearch_data create the file english.ths

   > tv : television

   - Execute the query:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY en_ths (
    Template = thesaurus,
    DictFile = mythesaurus,
    Dictionary = pg_catalog.english_stem);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION en_ths(COPY='simple');
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION en_ths
    ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart,
        word, hword, hword_part
    WITH en_ths, english_stem;
```

Now you can test it:

```sql
test=# SELECT to_tsvector('en_ths', 'tv');
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'televis':1
(1 row)

test=# SELECT to_tsvector('en_ths', 'television');
 to_tsvector 
-------------
 'televis':1
(1 row)
```